# stored proc recursion in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, function, recursion

I have a situation where I want to have a stored proc returning a table that calls itself recursively as part of its calculation.

Unfortunately SQL Server is having none of this and gives me an error along the lines of both being unable to declare a cursor that already exists and about not being able to nest and insert exec statement.

Could I get around some of these issues by using a function?  Is there another better way to do this?

The calculation is inherently recursive in nature, so there isn't any getting around this using joins as far as I can tell.

EDIT: to clarify the actual calculation since the code is complicated by other stuff and might complicate the matter-

suppose table A has columns (containerID, objID, objType, weight) and table B has columns (itemID, value).

objType in table A tells you whether objID in table A is a containerID (again in table A) or is and itemID from table B.

(containerID, objID) is a primary key on table A as is itemID on table B.

Generally a container will have tens to hundreds of items or other containers in it.  Hopefully the recursion depth isn't more than a dozen levels.  (guessing)  The calculation is to get a weighted average.

Comment: I'd like to know more about the calculation... functions will no doubt play a role, but you'd be surprised some of the insane things you can do with subqueries and views.   I like cursors, but they are often maligned...

Comment: Could you provide a little more information - especially relating to the nature of the recursive sproc.

Comment: Is this SQL Server? If you are using SQL 2008 you can use a recursive CTE to accomplish most tasks without needing a cursor at all. How about a code sample so we can see what you are trying to do?

Comment: Suppose you have a table full of records of some kind.  Then you have a table full of pairs of (container, record, weight) or (container, container, weight) combinations saying what is in each container.  If you want to do a weighted average over the records in a container in this second table, the (container, container) pairs necessitate some recursion here.  

If it's helpful imagine the containers being something like stock indices and the records being stocks.

Comment: might not actually be necessary to do recursion in a procedure (or at all). If you post a DDL and a better description of this calculation, we might be able to come up with a query, possibly non-recursive. To start with, have you looked into aggregate functions to do the calculation in-query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you provide very little information, as a result here is a guess: try using [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx), try set based operations and not a cursor, or try using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

This article gives 7 different ways to do what you're trying to do.

1. Recursive CTE methods
2. The blackbox XML methods
3. Using Common Language Runtime.
4. Scalar UDF with recursion
5. Table valued UDF with a WHILE loop.
6. Dynamic SQL
7. The Cursor approach.

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/#_Toc205129484

Answer (score 0):

I think you get an error because the same cursor name is probably used by every recursive call, and the nested call can't open a cursor of the same name until the parent call closes the cursor. If possible, can you make the cursor name dynamic, maybe something as simple as `SOME_CURSOR_{$RECURSION_DEPTH}`, and you might have to add the recursion depth as a parameter to the procedure though.  I've never done anything like this in SQL Server though so I'm not 100% sure.

Not sure about the next/insert exec problem, though it might be tied to the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the cursor with LOCAL scope may resolve the issue.  Although I'm not sure how the cursor would act in a recursive context.

Check out this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189238.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE StudentdIDCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR SELECT ...blahblah
```

The key is the `LOCAL` term. It will generate a separate cursor definition behind the scenes every time.